# animateTransform not working in IE 11

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

I am new to svg animation and below is my code for animating(moving up and down) a line above another line. This works perfectly in Mozilla and Chrome, but doesn't work in IE 11.
Can anyone help me with what I am missing. ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>

</head>
<body>
 <svg height="210" width="500">
 <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
 <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 153);stroke-width:2">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      values="200 200;-150 -150;200 200"
      begin="0s"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
 </line>
 </svg>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE does not support SMIL. You can add support by using [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) though

Comment: Is it a good practice to use <animateTransform> or is there any substitute for this, since adding libraries (fakesmile) increases the loading time.?

Comment: You could write your own animation library I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

IE and Edge don't appear to support SMIL or CSS transforms; the transform attribute would need to be set in order to have an impact on the translation/position, rotation/orientation, or skew etc.

Oddly enough, javascript is able to compute applied transforms using CSS, including part animations that use either keyframes or transition effects, even if they aren't being rendered in the browser. With this in mind, you can give your line some form of identifier, animate it using css, then apply the transform attribute manually every 50ms (~20 frames per second).

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
<line id="line" x1="150" y1="150" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 153);stroke-width:2"></line>
</svg>

<style>
    // Switch to CSS Animations
    @-webkit-keyframes line-animate {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 200px);
                    transform: translate(200px, 200px);
        }
        50% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-150px, -150px);
                    transform: translate(-150px, -150px);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 200px);
                    transform: translate(200px, 200px);
        }
    }
    @keyframes line-animate {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 200px);
                    transform: translate(200px, 200px);
        }
        50% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-150px, -150px);
                    transform: translate(-150px, -150px);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 200px);
                    transform: translate(200px, 200px);
        }
    }
    #line {
        -webkit-animation: line-animate 5s linear infinite;
                animation: line-animate 5s linear infinite;
    }
</style>
<script>
    (function(){
        var line = document.getElementById('line');
        // Iterative function
        line.animate = function() {
            // Set the line transform attribute to match the calculated CSS transform value.
            line.setAttribute('transform', getComputedStyle(line).getPropertyValue('transform'));
            setTimeout(line.animate, 50);
        };
        line.animate();
    })();
</script>
```

**Notes regarding this approach**

- Browsers which read CSS animations and transforms correctly may cause compounding issues when the transform attribute is set, so it would be best to also add some browser detection for IE. Regardless, most browsers will ignore the transform attribute when the style transform has been applied.
- If the SVG element that you wish to animate already has a transform attribute, then you will need to convert all points, distances and paths to the transformed values.
- Transform values will need to be recalculated for SMIL animations that use addition.
- A limit may need to be set on the number of elements being animated, in order to prevent issues with browser performance, as I expect `getComputedStyle` to be fairly resource intensive.